# Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file and data are supported by the default ESM loader

Tags: javascript

I run the discord.js bot via node --experimental-json-modules bot.js.
Then writes this:

```
Slash Commands (Global) started refreshing app.
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file and data are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at throwIfUnsupportedURLScheme (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1059:11)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1135:3)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:525:22)
    at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:110:35)
    at importModuleDynamicallyCallback (node:internal/process/esm_loader:35:14)
    at client.handleEvents (file:///C:/Users/kefaz0r/Desktop/abb/src/functions/handleEvents.js:6:32) {
  code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME'
}

Node.js v18.14.0
```

I tried to run the bot as well and got this error.

Answer (score 0):

It's a package version-related issue, If you are getting this issue with the NX monorepo workspace while running the server( nx serve server ) then try to update the nx & nrwl packages from v16.1.4 to v16.1.0.